# How do I set permissions so an IAM can upload to an Amazon S3 bucket in C#?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've created a user in IAM, and attached 2 managed policies: AmazonS3FullAccess and AdministratorAccess. I would like to upload files to an S3 bucket called "pscfront".

I am using the following code to do the upload:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.AmazonWebServices.AccessKey, Constants.AmazonWebServices.SecretKey);
            using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                var loc = client.GetBucketLocation("s3.amazonaws.com/pscfront");
                var tu = new TransferUtility(client);
                tu.Upload(filename, Constants.AmazonWebServices.BucketName, keyName);
 }
```

This fails with the exception "AccessDenied" (inner exception "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.") at the call to GetBucketLocation, or at the tu.Upload call if I comment that line out.

Any idea what gives?

Answer (score 0):

*smdh*

Nothing wrong with the persmissions -- I was setting the bucket name incorrectly.You just pass the plan bucket name -- "pscfront" in this case.